# AWS s3 cp with random date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, cp

i´m a newbie. My goal is to parametrize a date path in aws s3 cp command inside a pyspark script. The files are uploaded once a month in a undefined day, say process_date = DDMMYYYY where MM is current month and YYYY is current year

This is the command:

```
os.system(f'aws s3 cp {root_folder}{date_of_file_upload}/ {destination_folder} --recursive')
```

and these are the variable i´m using:

```
process_monthyear = process_date[2:4] + process_date[4:]
root_folder = 's3://company-id-files/'
destination_folder = '/tmp/company-id-files/'
date_of_file_upload = f'*{lit(process_monthyear)}' #wildcard * won´t work here
```

[Files in S3 folders in DDMMYYYY format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Tij.png)

Considering image above, if i manually input `date_of_file_upload = ´11092021´` everything works nicely. The problem is.. since i´m unable to control future upload dates (what day of the month the files will be uploaded), is there a way to parametrize this date_of_file_upload variable?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear why you can't simply calculate the needed date rather than hard-coding it. Also, standardized date formats such as ISO8601 YYYY-MM-DD are generally preferred over locale-specific date formats such as the UK's DDMMYYYY.

Comment: Dear @jarmod. Could you give an example on how to "calculate the needed date"? About the format, i agree with you, but these files come from third-party servers with this UK´s format. All future process_dates will be in ISO format for me

Comment: What date do you actually want? Example: `dt = date(2022, 2, 23)` and then format to string via some variant of `dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`. More [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime).